# Dearrangements and $e$

Tags: probability, infinitary-combinatorics

I have often heard a nice way that $e$ can appear in probability theory -- that, say, I had an **abitrarily large** box of specialty chocolates (so they are all unique), and I mixed them all up. The probability that such a mixture of chocolate is **completely mixed** (as in there is no chocolates that are in their original place) approaches $\frac{1}{e}$

**ATTEMPT:**

Let $D_n$ be the number ways of dearranging.
So we might realise that for some pair of chocolates $A,B$ there is the case where $A$ gets swapped with $B$ and thus the remaining number of ways to dearrange becomes $D_{n-2}$, Or the second case may be when $A$ gets placed into the place for some $C\neq B,A$. And then $B$ is then put into one of the remaining $(n-2)$ positions (as it cannot occupy its oringal slot, or the slot that $A$ has just been put into.

At this point, I feel that their is some obvious recurrence formula (as the $D_{n-2}$ term appears, and this would appear to continue) but I can't quite see it. Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: The notation is different, but you can find the recurrence $D_n=(n-1)D_{n-1}+D_{n-2}$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements), along with a brief proof.

Comment: Ah, this is exactly the problem! Thank you for the link :)

Comment: My pleasure! $\,$